# sequelize.js with nested Insert

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am working with `sequelize.js`, Where I have a table (say `User`) with different string fields and a many-to-many relation with another table (say `Nationality`).

I am trying to insert a new row of `User` with all the sub-element and the nationality, in one single instruction. Now I am doing like this:

```
models.Nation.create({codice:"IT",name:"Italia"}).then(function(italy){
      models.User.create({username:"local_u",nation:italy}).then(function(){

     });
});
```

If I look at the database, at the newly created `User` row`: the field`NationId` is not set.

I know I can use the function `setNation` of sequelize, but I wonder if I can do it within one single `User.create`.

Comment: btw you need to return the second one. `return models.User.create...`

Comment: huh, interesting! Is it necessary? or just philosophically required? because things are working without the return

Comment: it's necessary, so no errors would go undetected. currently the `Nation.create` promise won't catch errors in `User.create`. Bluebird should warn you about this already.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create the user entity with nation in one step using include. Something like this (code not tested):

```
models.Nation.create({ codice: "IT", name: "Italia" }).then(function (italy) {
    models.User.create({
        username: "local_u",
        nation: italy

    }, {
            include: [models.nation]
        }
    ).then(function () {/*Do Something*/});
});
```

It's an old question but hopefully will help someone.